# Efficiently filter React TreeView using search text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, treeview, full-text-search

I'm using Carbon component `TreeView` in my React application to render a nested list of elements. I need to add a search filter on this structure so as to efficiently filter all items matching the search text. If search text is empty, then display all items.

I checked some of the solutions here, but they are not very efficient. Also, I would like to implement the search on the Carbon component `TreeView`.

How can I achieve this with the best time complexity considering the tree can get very complex and data intensive?

```
import { TreeNode, TreeView } from "@carbon/react";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function CustomTreeView(props) {
   const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

   const renderTree = ({ nodes }) => {
      return nodes.map(({ items, ...nodeProps }) => {
         return (
            <TreeNode
              id="unique-id-per-node"
              ...
              ...
            >
            {renderTree({
                        nodes: items
                    })}
            </TreeNode>
         );
      );
   };

   return (
      <div>
         <TreeView
                label="Tree View"
                hideLabel={true}
                className="treeView"
            >
                {renderTree({
                   nodes: globalStore.apis,
                   withIcons: true
                })}
            </TreeView>
      </div>
   );
}

export default CustomTreeView;
```

Here, `globalStore` refers to the passed context which contains all the application data.